# What will be used by search engines when you specify both <title> and meta name=title

Tags: meta-tags

I have a web page in which the `<title>` element under `<head>` is different than `<meta name="title"

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<meta name="title" content="Welcome to blablabla site!" />
</head>
<body>
somebody
</body>
</html>
```

Will search engines/google show as title "Welcome to blablabla site" or the title welcome?

The idea is that these values are coming from CMS and the content team wants the meta title to be shown differently than the browser title for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<meta name="title"...>` tag does not affect search engines, and as far as I know, it is not a web standard of any sort. If the CMS is generating this tag, it's likely due to an internal feature or quirk of the CMS.

To answer your question about these two tags, search engines will read and take into account only the `<title>` tag. While search results often show the `<title>` tag verbatim, be aware it's also normal for them to decide to modify or ignore it.

Comment: It is a custom CMS in which a particular company stores the posts. Although this is not a web standard, the meta title is supported by many famous CMSs like Wordpress, Strapi SEO plugin etc... The content team fill the title inside seo component and want to use it for search engines but display something else in the web page.  Thanks for the info that is good to know that only the <title> is used by search engines

Comment: @KristiJorgji The HTML `<title>` element is often called the "title meta tag". Perhaps there is some confusion stemming from the nomenclature. I haven't heard of any software that supports a `<meta name="title"` tag. Usually when a CMS or plugin creates a "title meta tag", their actual HTML output is the `<title>` element.

Comment: Additional context at [this Stack Overflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076201/difference-between-meta-name-title-tag-and-title-title-tag#comment31701824_21076311). - "The `<meta name="title" ...>` element will most probably be ignored, as it is not mentioned in any specification or public draft or even at wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions. It is, like so many `meta` tags, a write-only tag, with illusionary effects only."